# Removing master layout from view (MVC2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, spark-view-engine

if i need remove master layout from my view, how can i do it in MVC2?
i tried put code in my view that was shown in documentation http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/master-layouts: , but it still bring my Application.spark layout :-/

any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but what if you create and empty master layout, and say `<use master="EmptyMaster" />` in the top of your view? Or you could call on the empty master from the controller; `return View("View", "EmptyMaster");`

Don't know if it'll work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: that's what i did. 
p.s. don't really these small hacks

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is a litle (maybe a lot) late but you can also use the [PartialView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview.aspx) method if you mean to render an HTML fragment instead of the full page.

Relevant Spark [documentation](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/master-layouts#SelectingLayout)

> - An Application.spark file in the Views/Layouts folder or Views/Shared folder
>
> This is the most general-purpose way to have a site-wide master template. It will not be used if the controller returns a **PartialView()**.