# How do you return a partial view with spark?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am using the SparkViewEngine and I am calling an action that I want to return a Partial View to update just a section of the page.  When I return the view on the action the masterpage and all of its content gets returned.  How do you tell a partial in spark to just return the content of the partial view and not put the content inside the application.spark file??

Comment: BTW, here's a very similar question from a little over a month ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131936/removing-master-layout-from-view-mvc2/2520319

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you return PartialViewResult?

```
public PartialViewResult ActionName()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

If you use PartialView(), application.spark is ignored.